# How to add dynamically multiple objects of key value inside an array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

**I am very confused about array of objects keys add dynamically based on for loop. I have searched and tried a lot but i could not get proper solution as i want.**

*Firstly I would like to share my code please go though with it...*

```
foreach ($allData as $key => $value)
{ foreach ($value as $key2 => $val2)
  {
       $data = 
       array( 'metafield'=> array( 
           "key" => "$key2", 
           "value" => "$val2", 
           "type" => "single_line_text_field",
            "namespace"=> "meta" ) 
            );
    print_r(json_encode($data)
    );
  echo "<br>"; 
  } 
 }
```

*With the Help of this code I get output like below*

```
{"metafield": 
  {"key":"length","value":"12","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
  }
{"metafield": 
  {"key":"height","value":"6.5","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
 }
{"metafield": 
  {"key":"waist","value":"33","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
  }
{"metafield": 
  {"key":"leg","value":"54","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
  }
```

*And I want output like this..*

```
{"metafield":
{"key":"length","value":"12","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
{"key":"height","value":"6.5","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
{"key":"waist","value":"33","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
{"key":"leg","value":"54","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
 }
```

It would be appreciated for answers and suggestions. THANK YOU

Comment: `$data['matafield'][] = 'key' ...`

Comment: Can you elaborate more actually i have tried this method but it does not work ..?

Comment: Your problem is that you create each loop 'metafield', `$data['metafield'][] = [key" => "$key2", "value" => "$val2","type" => "single_line_text_field", "namespace"=> "meta"]` and outside the `foreach`: `print_r(json_encode($data));`

Comment: Ohk .. lemme try this one

Comment: its give something more complected result like  at first  [0] and [1] index store  last index ( key and value ) after become nested array ..?

Comment: Please provide us complete example you some fiddle php

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, as Simone Rossaini commented, for you to get only one "metafield" you need to put it of the loop.

Second, the way you expect the output means its only one key with an array as value, like:

```
{"metafield": [
{"key":"length","value":"12","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
{"key":"height","value":"6.5","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
{"key":"waist","value":"33","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
{"key":"leg","value":"54","type":"single_line_text_field","namespace":"meta"}
]}
```

It's hard to provide a sample code without knowing how your data is structured, but you could put the data into an array and then set is as value to the "metafield" key on your original array, something like:

```
//How I *imagine* your "$allData" is structured 
$allData = array(
    ["key" => "length", "value" => "12", "type" => "single_line_text_field", "namespace" => "meta"],
    ["key" => "length", "value" => "6.5", "type" => "single_line_text_field", "namespace" => "meta"],
    ["key" => "length", "value" => "33", "type" => "single_line_text_field", "namespace" => "meta"],
    ["key" => "length", "value" => "54", "type" => "single_line_text_field", "namespace" => "meta"]
);


//Defining a array to be the value of the key 'metafield' in your "$data"
$metafield = array();


//Pushing the data from the "$allData" into the "$metafield" array
foreach ($allData as $input) {

// The code below depends on how your data is structured, but it gives the idea
    array_push($metafield, $input); 
}


//attributing the $metafield array as value to the 'metafield' key in your data
$data = array(
    'metafield' => $metafield
);


print(json_encode($data));
```

Feel free to ask anything :)

Comment: If I go with your code its really tough to post data. actually I would to tell reason for this result is that I want POST data through PHP CURL and its necessary to add objects with a key which is 'metafield'. 
And for your code it's become more impossible challenge. Because for requesting Data I have to apply loop and that's not work on your code

Comment: Again, its hard to provide a good sample code without knowing how your "$allData" is structured, but I'll edit my answer in a way that may clarify what I mean, so check that out and feel free to respond =]